# Transmit binary file to device using BLE

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, bluetooth-lowenergy, capacitor, arraybuffer

I am working on an app which can read device information via bluetooth BLE. So far I've been able to connect to the device and read certain properties like state of charge and firmware version number on iOS, Android, and within Chrome. However, now I'm at the point where I need to update the firmware and I am confused how to do so.

Little back story, the app is written in Ionic + Vue + Capacitor so everything is JavaScript/TypeScript. So the BLE plugin I'm using is the [Capacitor Community Bluetooth LE](https://github.com/capacitor-community/bluetooth-le). Within the documentation it has a `write` method which wants `deviceId`, `service`, `characteristic`, and `value`. I know what I need to use for the first 3, but `value` is suppose to be [`DataView`](https://github.com/capacitor-community/bluetooth-le#dataview). Somehow I need to take a binary bin file and transmit it via this write command. I noticed that `DataView` is an `ArrayBuffer` with `byteLength` and `byteOffset`. I don't really know how to get my file into this format.

Assuming I have `deviceId`, `service`, `characteristic`, how can I grab this file and transmit a `DataView` using this write method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you had any progress with this? I waS thinking about the same thing today

Comment: No progress but I went a different direction. Since the time of this post the plugin has had a lot of changes.

Answer (score 0):

The native SDKs offer a "Socked"-based communication directly over the L2CAP protocol. (GATT uses L2CAP internaly)

### Android

- Open a L2CAP Channel via [`BluetoothAdapter#listenUsingL2capChannel()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter#listenUsingL2capChannel())
- Connect to the L2CAP Channel via [`BluetoothDevice#createL2capChannel(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice#createL2capChannel(int))

### iOS

- Open a L2CAP Channel via [`CBPeripheralManager#publishL2CAPChannel()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheralmanager/2880160-publishl2capchannel)
- Connect to the L2CAP Channel via [`CBPeripheral#openL2CAPChannel(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice#createL2capChannel(int))

When a L2CAP Channel is registered an PSM (the "Port") is allocated by the device. This number must be communicated to the other peers. This could be done by including the number in the BLE advertisement or by exposing it over a GATT Characteristic